# Monkey in a maze express $E[X|Y_1=i]$ with $E(X)$

Tags: probability

I have the following question :

There is a monkey in a maze with three different entrances $1,2,3$ if he choose entrance:

Number $1$ he will get out of the maze in $7$ hours

Number $2$ he will get stuck in the maze for 3 hours and then return to the starting point of choosing three different entrances

Number $3$ he will get stuck in the maze for 5 hours and then return to the starting point of choosing three different entrances

The monkey choose an entrance in equal probability every time of the three entrances in an independently of his previous choosing Let $X$ the time until the monkey got out of the maze

Question :

Let $Y_1$ be the first choose the monkey makes find for $i=2,3$. Express $E[X|Y_1=i]$ with $E(X)$

**This is what I did:**

I made two different cases 
$$ E(X|Y_{1}=2)$$

$$E(X|Y_{1}=3)$$

I did the first case using the formula of expected value

$$E(X|Y_{1}=2)=\sum_{x\in R_{x}}x*P(X=x|Y_{1}=2)$$

Now since we know he'll be at least 3 hours in the maze we change index

$$E(X|Y_{1}=2)=\sum_{x\in R_{x}}x*P(X=x|Y_{1}=2)=\sum_{x\in R_{x}}(x+3)*P(X=x+3)$$

Now I'm stuck, I think that the right answer is $E(X)+3$ in the first case, yet I don't find how to reach it using the formula I have tried number of different methods all doesn't seem to work. I'm thinking about this problem for a few hours now, and can't find any leads.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have edited your question. Please check if I have done it correctly or not.

Comment: @Rohan Yes, Thank you.

Comment: In the last step, it should be $(x+3)P(X=x)$. You should use logic before any formula. If you knew that on average the monkey needs $E[x]$ hours, how many hours you think it needs on average if it choosed the second door initially?

Comment: The intuition is that I need to add $3$ meaning $E(X|Y_1=2)=3+E(X)$ Yet I'm looking to show it using the formulas or any other method that is not based on intuition, since intuition is not an answer.

Comment: You are there. Again, the last step should be $\sum (x+3)P(X=x)$ which is equal to $\sum xP(X=x) + \sum 3P(X=x) = E[x] +3$.

Comment: Why $\sum 3P(X=x)=3$?

Comment: The probability that $X$ has any value is 1 of course, and if you multiply it by 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${\rm E}(X|Y_1=2)=3+{\rm E}(X)$, ${\rm E}(X|Y_1=3)=5+{\rm E}(X)$, so
$${\rm E}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^3 {\rm P}(Y_1=i){\rm E}(X|Y_1=i) = \frac13(7+3+{\rm E}(X)+5+{\rm E}(X))$$
and finally
$${\rm E}(X)=3\times5=15$$

Comment: Why is this true? $E(X|Y_1=2)=3+E(X)$

Comment: Because if you (well, the monkey ! :-) choose door $2$, then you spent 3 hours in the maze and are basically back to the initial conditions. Mind you, this reasoning doesn't prove ${\rm E}(X)$ is $15$, just that *if* $X$ has an expectation, it *has* to be $15$.

Comment: I'm looking to show that $E(X|Y_1=2)=3+E(X)$  using the formulas or any other method that is not based on intuition, Is it possible to reach to this equality using the formula?

Answer (score 2):

Basically since all outcomes are equally likely, we can consider that the monkey either finds the correct path (+7h) or a wrong path (+4h on average) and returns to starting point. Then the average time to finish is given by:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{i-1}(7+4(i-1))$$

And developing the sum and noting that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}k^{i-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}k^i=\frac{1}{1-k}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ik^{i-1}=\frac{1}{(1-k)^2}$$

we find that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{i-1}(7+4(i-1))=15$$